# How to debug an android app through Remote Desktop Connection?

Tags: android, remote-debugging

I am working in my home with my personal pc with which I connect to a PC in the office. I need to run an app to test it on my phone(Android and the app is Xamarin). I've turned on developers mode on the phone and I've checked the option that enables debugging through USB. I have the usb connected to my PC and I'm connected remotely. I've googled what to do and it says that I need to check the boxes in the local resources tab in the Remote Desktop Connection window(like disks and stuff i'm going to connect to later). I've done that on both PC's but only my disks(C:, D:...) show and not the phone when I'm connected with USB. Am I doing something wrong and is there another way of getting my phone to show up on the PC through the RDC?